# Is it possible to use an autoscaling/v2beta2 HPA with apiregistration.k8s.io/v1 APIService?

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, kubernetes-metrics

I've created a deployment which exposes a custom metric through an endpoint and an APIService that registers this custom metric, so I can use it in an HPA to autoscale the deployment. To achieve this, I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/building-your-own-custom-metrics-api-for-kubernetes-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-277473dea2c1).

It worked well while using an apiregistration.k8s.io/**v1beta1** APIService. The metric was exposed correctly and the HPA could read it and scale accordingly. I've tried to update the APIService to version apiregistration.k8s.io/**v1** (as v1beta1 is deprecated and removed in Kubernetes v1.22), but then the HPA couldn't pick the metric anymore, with this message:

```
Message
-------
unable to get metric threatmessages: Service on test services-metrics-service/unable to fetch 
metrics from custom metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request 
(get services.custom.metrics.k8s.io services-metrics-service)
```

If I manually request the metric, it exists though:

```sh
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/test/services/services-metrics-service/threatmessages |jq .
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metricName": "threatmessages",
      "timestamp": "2021-02-09T14:43:39.321Z",
      "value": "0",
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Service",
        "namespace": "test",
        "name": "services-metrics-service",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are my APIService and HPA resources:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  group: custom.metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 1000
  versionPriority: 5
  service:
    name: services-metrics-service
    namespace: test
    port: 443
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: services-parallel-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: services-parallel-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      describedObject:
        kind: Service
        name: services-metrics-service
      metric:
        name: threatmessages
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 4k
  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 30
      policies:
      - type: Pods
        value: 1
        periodSeconds: 30
```

What am I doing wrong? Or are these 2 versions just not compatible for some reason?

Comment: Provide some details about your environment (local, cloud), what k8s version are you using. Did you try to add `hostNetwork.enabled: true`? How did you get custom.metrics with `Prometheus` adapter or `stackdriver`? Can you check if you have any suspicious in metrics logs?

Comment: What K8s version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kubernetes version 1.19

Comment: can you provide answer from my 1st comment?

Answer (score 1):

According to [APIService 1.22](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#apiservice-v122) documentation you can find information:

> - Migrate manifests and API clients to use the apiregistration.k8s.io/v1 API version, available since v1.10.
> - All existing persisted objects are accessible via the new API
> - No notable changes

First of all, `v1` is available for the version you are using (v.1.19).

Secondly, and more important, `All existing persisted objects are accessible via the new API` and `No notable changes`. This means that the objects created using `v1beta1` don't need to be updated or modified. They will be available and working even if they were created using `v1beta1`. That is, after upgrading to version `v 1.22`, you should have no issue, the same objects will simply be accessible (and, I would think, accessed by `HPA`) as if they had been created using `v1`. What is more, they may already (in version `1.19`) be accessible as `v1`, as I will explain next, so you can check now if everything is fine.

I have run some quick tests on a `v 1.19` `GKE cluster` and found if something contains `apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1` (in fact, using exactly what the OP provided in in question:

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  group: custom.metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 1000
  versionPriority: 5
  service:
    name: services-metrics-service
    namespace: test
    port: 443
  version: v1
```

except using `v1beta1` as `apiVersion`) is applied, and then a get command is used to obtain what was created  `$ kubectl get apiservices/v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io --output=json`, an object marked with apiVersion `v1`, not `v1beta1`, will be obtained (`"apiVersion": "apiregistration.k8s.io/v1"`). And if, intead, `apiVersion .../v1` is used during the creation instead of `apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1`, the same is obtained. If either of those is deleted, the other one is gone. It is the same object behind the scenes. Yet it is marked as `v1`.

As a result of all the above, you should simply revert back to what you were doing when you deployed using `v1beta1`, given it worked and will keep on working according to [APIService 1.22](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#apiservice-v122) documentation. You can also run `$ kubectl get apiservices/v1.custom.metrics.k8s.io --output=json` command, either `$ kubectl get APIService --output=json` or `$ kubectl get APIService.apiregistration.k8s.io --output=json` once deployed `v1beta1` version, to understand if object is already marked as using `v1` behind the scenes despite having created the object with `v1beta1` - like is happening in my case.

Creating objects with `v1` is not necessary if they were already created with `v1beta1`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that I will be able to use my `v1beta1` object in K8s v1.22+. But I don't know if I will be able to CREATE new `v1beta1` objects. If I won't I'd have to update my object definition to use `v1`(which doesn't work for me). Depending on the answer to that question, I'd say this answers helps me or not. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: As mention in docs `The apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1 API version of APIService will no longer be served in v1.22.` I guess it might be deprecated in 1.22 and only `v1` will be acceptable. This will be known for sure when 1.22 comes live